# Google Maps for iOS Overlay Accessibility issues

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm trying to add markers and overlays to the map. I need the markers to be voiceover accessible, but not the overlays.

I have tried turning off the accessibility for the overlay, but the app crashes if I do...

```
 func addOverlays() {
    removeOverlays()
    guard let definitions = FanX.MapPrefs.arenaOverlays else { return }
    self.mapOverlays = definitions.map { definition -> Overlay in
        let groundOverlay = GMSGroundOverlay(bounds: definition.bounds, icon: definition.image)
        groundOverlay.map = self.mapView

        groundOverlay.isAccessibilityElement = false // Crashes the app

        return Overlay(definition: definition, groundOverlay: groundOverlay)
    }
}
```

Error Log

```
2019-07-18 14:37:12.943324-0500 FanX[76986:14936979] -[GMSGroundOverlay setIsAccessibilityElement:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000283a000

2019-07-18 14:37:12.964699-0500 FanX[76986:14936979] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[GMSGroundOverlay setIsAccessibilityElement:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000283a000'
```